# Drawing squares on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw squares when I click on Google map.
How can I write it in a code ?
As you see below it is my code to draw circles but I want to draw squares 
Please help me ....

```
public class Map extends  Activity implements OnMapClickListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;

Circle myCircle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


 FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
 myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
 myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 myMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) { 

    int b=3;

 CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
 .center(point)   //set center
 .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
 .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
 .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
 .strokeWidth(5);

 for(int c=0; c < b ; c++){
 myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
}
}
```

Comment: what you want is called a PolyLine. Well documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ give it a look and an attempt and then update this if you have issues!

Comment: No I want to draw squares like circles or triangle on Google map

Comment: Not PolyLine but Polygon is probably what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polygons

Comment: See it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567058/drawing-a-rectangle-onto-a-google-map